Use ip command for the first time and the result is disastrous: Temporary failure in name resolution
My Linux distro is Debian 12.8.0, 64bit, English.
I have installed the packages ifupdown, iproute2 and macchanger
I consulted the below posts before I ask for help here:
iproute2 command to enable a IPv4 address
ip link set not assigning IP Address but ifup does
Task-centered iproute2 user guide
Note: I have no problems with bringing up and down the network interface using the package ifupdown and am able to access the internet.
The contents of /etc/network/interfaces are
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug enxfe5953ed38a0
#iface enxfe5953ed38a0 inet static
#   address 192.168.1.50/24
#   gateway 192.168.1.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
#   dns-nameservers 9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112

The contents of /etc/network/script/home-lan are
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enxfe5953ed38a0
iface enxfe5953ed38a0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.50/24
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8

I created a bash script called lan-new-up, made it executable and placed it in /usr/local/bin
Its contents are:
#!/bin/bash
sudo macchanger -r enxfe5953ed38a0
sudo cp /etc/network/script/home-lan /etc/network/interfaces.d 
#sudo ifup enxfe5953ed38a0
sudo ip link set dev enxfe5953ed38a0 up
sudo ip address add 192.168.1.50/24 dev enxfe5953ed38a0
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev enxfe5953ed38a0

After executing the script lan-new-up, I got the error as shown below:
username@hostname:~$ lan-new-up
[sudo] password for username: 
Current MAC:   02:b3:c2:9f:0a:90 (unknown)
Permanent MAC: 02:b3:c2:9f:0a:90 (unknown)
New MAC:       fe:59:53:ed:38:a0 (unknown)
username@hostname:~$ ping yahoo.com
ping: yahoo.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Thanks for your help.

Your script only replicates the "address/netmask" and "gateway" settings from ifupdown, but forgot to replicate the "dns-nameservers" setting.
DNS is not managed through ip; it's configured through /etc/resolv.conf (usually).

If the system has the resolvconf tool installed, as your ifupdown configuration mentions, then it should be used to add entries to resolv.conf since it somewhat helps different tools cooperate:

echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" | resolvconf -a enxfe5953ed38a0


resolvconf -a enxfe5953ed38a0 <<END
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
END


If the system has systemd-resolved and resolvectl installed (and the systemd-resolved service running), then that should be used instead:

resolvectl dns enxfe5953ed38a0 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8

When systemd-resolved is in use, /etc/resolv.conf should point to 127.0.0.53.

If neither is installed, then you need to edit /etc/resolv.conf by hand:

/etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8




Thanks for your help. After going through this experience, I much prefer using ifupdown to ip. I noticed now that if I use ifupdown, I do NOT have to add DNS nameservers to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf/base. The script home-lan in /etc/network/interfaces.d/ manages my preferred DNS nameservers. In contrast, using ip requires me to add DNS nameservers to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base. [Like you wrote, ip doesn't manage DNS nameservers.

That's kind of the whole point of ifupdown. Like several other packages, ifupdown exists to provide unified management on top of all the low-level tools.
